# Splitting multiple, spaced-list values in Python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a very simple list where it looks like this:

```py
['20 32 35 47 64', '15 17 25 32 53', '07 10 12 61 65', '08 14 31 58 68', '01 10 44 47 56']
```

What I would like to do is to split the values within each list where the values are displayed as follows:

```py
[20,32,35,47,64,15,17,25,32,53,07,10,12,61,65,..]
```

```py
myvallist = myvalues.split(" ")
print (myvallist)
```

For some reason, when I attempt to use the .split(), pyCharm is throwing an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VFARETR.CENTRAL\Desktop\pyCharm\megaTest", line 25, in <module>
    myvallist = myvalues.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: `myvalues` is a list. Call `split()` on each *element* of the list.

Comment: You have to call `split` on each of the items *inside* `myvallist`, not on the list itself.  e.g. `[v.split(' ') for v in myvallist]`.  Then you can flatten that list as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/3282436).

Comment: `' '.join(myvalues).split()`

Comment: `myvallist = [int(v) for v in " ".join(myvalues).split()]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to split the list, not the string. Try this:

```
input_list = ['20 32 35 47 64', '15 17 25 32 53', '07 10 12 61 65', '08 14 31 58 68', '01 10 44 47 56']
complete_list = []
for sub_list in input_list:
    current_items = sub_list.split()
    complete_list.extend([i for i in current_items])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions are working - which is a good thing in that I know I wasn't going crazy.

and, to answer your question, it does not matter if it is a string or number - so long as I can query the list contents.

Comment: Sounds like you have something else going on with your input data then.

Comment: Does the code from this answer do what you expect it to do, if you copy and paste it (including the hard-coded input)? If not, how is the result different from what you expect? If it does work, can you see something special about your input that causes a problem?

Comment: complete_list = []
for sub_list in myvalues:
    current_items = sub_list.split()
    complete_list.extend([i for i in current_items])
['20 32 35 47 64', '15 17 25 32 53', '07 10 12 61 65', '08 14 31 58 68']

Answer (score 0):

It says so because your list consists of strings. You have to acces the string inside the list before you split the string.

```
 mylist = ['20 32 35 47 64', '15 17 25 32 53', '07 10 12 61 65',
          '08 14 31 58 68', '01 10 44 47 56']

myvallist = []

for item in mylist:
    myvallist += item.split(' ')  # adds the numbers of the current string to myvallist

print(myvallist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want the entries to be integers or strings but here's a solution with them as strings.

```
my_list = ['20 32 35 47 64', '15 17 25 32 53', '07 10 12 61 65', '08 14 31 58 68', '01 10 44 47 56']

my_new_list = [item for sublist in [item.split(" ") for item in my_list] for item in sublist]
```

The inner list comprehension splits each string by spaces and then the outer list comprehension then flattens the array produced.

Comment: It's possible to simplify this with an understanding of how nested comprehensions work: `item for string in my_list for item in string.split(' ')`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! I was certain there was a neater way to do it and this is really slick.

Comment: For reference: https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/